# What does the surface of a star with a radiative envelope look like?

Tags: star, main-sequence, stellar-structure

[image]
This image from Wikipedia shows that main sequence stars above 1.5 solar masses have a convective core and a radiative envelope. The surface of our sun grainy because of convection cells right below the photosphere. But massive main sequence stars wouldn't have this, since they don't have convective envelopes, right? So what would their surface look like?